# Dialog Activity also resumes other activities in the background

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the scenario. I have 2 activities in my application and a Dialog activity that is started when I click on the notification created by my application. 
The problem is that when I click on the notification, only the Dialog should show, not the other activity of my app, if it was stopped on pressing the home button.

When I close my application by pressing the back button, the dialog activity shows the dialog, but when the application is running in the background, that activity also opens up on creating the dialog activity.

I use `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` for my dialog activity.

How to only show the Dialog activity, not other activities in the backgroud?

Comment: Did you finish() your previous activity which starts the Dialog activity?

Comment: Dialog activity is stated by a notification.. What i want to do is that the main activity of the application should not come up upon creating the dialog activity, if the user doesnot closes the main activity by pressing the back key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the OP issue is setting a different Task affinity for that activity in the Manifest.

```
<activity android:name="MyIndependentActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
android:taskAffinity="a_unique_id">
```

The taskAffinity string must be **different from the package name** (com.whatever.myapp)

I also use android:excludeFromRecents="true", to hide the dialog from the recent apps list, as it usually makes no sense returning to a dialog.

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Affinities

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that'll happen.

When you declare a theme of Dialog it affects the activity lifecycle and the previous activity doesn't go into onStop so some Android functions still think it's the active activity which is technially true as your dialog Activity is acting like a dialog.

One possible work around if you don't 'care' that you can see the previous activity behind the dialog is to change the dialog to be a DialogFragment, put the theme of dialog on the fragment and show this in it's own activity, that'll do it.

Comment: How to do it?
What i exactly want to do is only the dialog activity should start, without affecting anything in the background.

I don't want to see the previous activity of my application.

Comment: But you will see it because it is in the Activity stack of your application. If you want the Dialog to run on it's own, use the `singleTask` launchMode in your AndroidManifest: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this (and this can't be the best way to do this) is to have some logic in the activity.onPause() and activity.onResume() methods, that will perform actions based on what I want. My experience is more around separate activities and transitioning between them than using dialogs alot.

You can pass information between activities through setResult(). This will enable you to work out why the child activity has decided to close. That combined with the onResume function should enable you to disable the parent activity.

To override the dialog so that the other activity is not visible behind it, is probably to use the onPause() method to make it go translucent.

I have found onStop() very irratic to use and often unnecessary. The reason for this, is that it is called unpredictably from a developers point of view because onStop can be called based at strange times based on whether the OS has enough memory etc. onPause however in my experience is always called predicably.

Comment: Let me try making the activity translucent on onPause. BTW another question: How to make it look like before in onResume? Do i have to setContentView again?

Comment: I believe it should already. If it doesn't then you could redo setContentView.

Comment: A good way of themeing your app, (ie translucent background) is to use styles/themes. You can see the OS defaults here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml